# Android set border for button while selected

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-studio, radio-group

I made a radio group and put some buttons(not radio button) inside, these buttons have only background color. I want to set the first button selected, and set a border to the button while selected.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_colour"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_yellow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_colour"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_yellow_effect"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:state_selected="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_pink"
        android:background="#ffff74c0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_yellow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_yellow"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_yellow"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_green"
        android:background="#ff00ff18"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_pink"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_pink"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_pink"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_red"
        android:background="#ffff0800"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_green"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_green"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_green"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_blue"
        android:background="#ff1bb0ff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_red"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_red"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_purple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#ffe200ff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_blue"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I tried to use selector on the first button, but is not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#1B5E91" />
        <solid
            android:color="#fffdff16"/>

        <size
            android:width="55dp"
            android:height="55dp" />
    </shape>
</item> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:background="#fffdff16" /> <!-- default -->
```

Comment: Did you set your selector as `background` for button?

Comment: yes for the first button `android:background="@drawable/button_yellow_effect"`

Comment: Are you trying to set button selected just by adding `android:state_selected="true"`?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure is that the right way to set button selected, I am new to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

`state_selected` better not to set by yourself - android system will spoil all you work logic. Instead of this try `state_activated` - both in layout xml and selector. Of course, you also can use special view background for `state_selected`, but, again, don't try to change that state by your code.

Comment: I changed `android:state_activated="true"` to both in layout and selector, but is still not working, logcat said nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the setSelected(); method for the button in the OnClick method Ex.

```
 button_yellow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            button_yellow.setSelected(true);

        }

    });
```